# RecyclerView adapter taking wrong values during scrolling

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have read several questions on stackoverflow addressing this problem but I could not solve my problem. The recyclerview shows webviews. My issue is that the adapter, initially, load the right values (below image):

[image: right behavior]

but when I scroll down, and scroll up to first position again, wrong values are displayed in webview  (below image):

[image: right behavior]

<del>I think this problem may originate from previously started loads into the webview</del>, but I don't have any idea about handling this behavior. Here is related parts of my code:

```
/* in my notation, pg is equivalent to page.*/
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ebook_list, container, false);
mEbookRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.ebook_recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mEbookRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
updateUI();
return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
updateUI();
}


private void updateUI() {
if (mAdapter == null) {
    EbookLab ebookLab = EbookLab.get(getActivity());
    List<String> pgs = ebookLab.getPgs();
    mAdapter = new EbookAdapter(pgs);
    mEbookRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}

   /* ******codes for preparation of menus which I have ignored *******/

private class EbookHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private String mPg;

public EbookHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_ebook, container, false));
    mListWebView = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_web_View);
    mListWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
}

public void bindEbook(String pg) {
    mPg = pg;
    mListWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "Stack Over Flow " + String.valueOf(glbPos), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
}

private class EbookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EbookHolder> {
private List<String> mPgs;
public EbookAdapter(List<String> pgs) {
    mPgs = pgs;
}
@Override
public EbookHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    return new EbookHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EbookHolder holder, int position) {
    String pg = mPgs.get(position);
    glbPos = position;//A global variable for position
    holder.bindEbook(pg);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPgs.size();
}
public void setPgs(List<String> pgs) {
    mPgs.clear();
    mPgs.addAll(pgs);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Any helps is appreciated.

**Update:**In my code , I defined mListWebView as a global variable. But it should be defined inside `private class EbookHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.
Then I removed `bindEbook(String pg)` method and directly updated `mListWevView`
 inside `public void onBindViewHolder(EbookHolder holder, int position)`:

```
holder.mListWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "Stack Over Flow " + String.valueOf(glbPos), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

**My Question >>** Does calling `bindEbook(String pg)` takes longer time compared to scrolling recyclerview or it is related to Android Architecture??

Comment: your viewholder is wrong

Comment: @ war_Hero: Can you give me more details?

Comment: post your adapter ill explain, JUST AS A JIST THE VIEW S INSIDE THE VIEWHOLDER ARE USED TO MAINTAIN THE POSITION

Comment: It takes more memory as the items are not recycled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try few things:
1) put `log` after `String pg = mPgs.get(position)`; and see, which `pg` value is after that line;
In `bindEbook()`:
2) put `log` to see which `pg` value is incoming;
3) put `mListWebView.clearHistory()` or `mListWebView.loadUrl("about:blank")` before `mListWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()` just to see is your `webview` really loading new page

Also - try to replace `webview` with simple `textView` - you will see, is problem in `webview` or in `adapter`.

Comment: Thank for you helpful answer. I find the solution.  I removed `bindEbook(String pg)` and directly updated webview in `onBindViewHolder` method. (1) and (2) are key points for solving the problem. (3) had no effect. The problem is in adapter. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem which I solved after extensive debugging. I hope this can help you:

In my project, I am showing a horizontal RecyclerView within a vertical RecyclerView. The code can be seen [here](https://github.com/bedawi/Smog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/benjamindahlhoff/smog/Adapters/MeasurementsAdapter.java) and [here](https://github.com/bedawi/Smog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/benjamindahlhoff/smog/Adapters/StationsAdapter.java) and I explained what I do on my website [here](http://benjamindahlhoff.de/2017/02/10/recyclerviews-at-work/).

I noticed that when scrolling down the outer (vertical) RecyclerView, the values of the inner (horizontal) RecyclerView where messed up. That is similar to your problem. Set some console log commands (Log.v) here and there in my inner RecyclerView adapter (called MeasurementsAdapter), one specifically in the inner view holder class, where the data is bound:
   public class MeasurementsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    [code omitted here]

```
public MeasurementsViewHolder (View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    [code omitted here]
}

public void bindMeasurement (String name, double value, String unit, int color) {
    mNameView.setText(name);
    mValueView.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(value)));
    mUnitsView.setText(unit);
    mBoxLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    // Log.v(TAG, name + " " + value); <-- here I was logging
}
```

I was observing that when I was scrolling at some point this "bindMeasurement" method was no longer executed.

My guess is that RecyclerView was "recycling" some random data. This is not what I wanted and my result looked like yours' very much.

So, after I read the notifyDataSetChanged-method in the RecyclerView documentation. In the adapter of my outer RecyclerView (called Stationsadapter) I modified the binding method in the inner ViewHolder class and execute the adapter.notifyDataHasChanged method there (see line 84 in [1](https://github.com/bedawi/Smog/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/benjamindahlhoff/smog/Adapters/MeasurementsAdapter.java))

```
   public class StationsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
       implements View.OnClickListener {public TextView mStationInfoView;
   private MeasurementsAdapter mMeasurementsAdapter;

   /**
    * Constructor of inner class StationsViewHolder
    * @param itemView
    */
   public StationsViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       [code omitted here]

   }

   /**
    * Bind weather station to view
    * @param station is a class containing data of one weather station
    */
   public void bindStation (Station station) {
       [code omitted here]
       mMeasurementsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Now my RecyclerViews show the right data. I very much hope this helps you and others.

Cheers
Ben